# How to backup and remove solaris zones?

Tags: solaris

Anyone know the commands to backup solaris zones?

If inside the solaris zone, i have also mounted to a separate directory in another network drive. How to make sure when during backup, the mounted files will also be copied over?

And also how to remove the solaris zones properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of filesystem your zonepath is,
if you are using zfs it could be just a matter of taking a snapshot and using zfs send
to a file.
Otherwise some methods are listed here 
http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/Zones_Best_Practices#Zone_Backups

I'd advise to backup any network drive (nfs share?) with a separate process ,using maybe a tar or cpio.

This is a good procedure to delete a zone
http://www.logiqwest.com/dataCenter/Demos/RunBooks/Zones/deleteZone.html

Comment: How to find out what kind of file system i am using

Comment: on global zone issue
/usr/sbin/zoneadm list -vi


         ......  PATH are your zone paths, then lookup the filesystem in /etc/vfstab
or try zfs list to see if you are using zfs