# How to restore solaris zone?

Tags: solaris

I posted an earlier question on how to backup and delete the solaris zone:
[How to backup and remove solaris zones?](https://serverfault.com/questions/319011/how-to-backup-and-remove-solaris-zones)

But i like to ask also how can i restore the solaris zone just in case next time i need to access the files or the environment inside the old solaris zone?

Comment: This would depend on how you chose to back up your zones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way I've done it.  Depends on whether you backed up the zone with the pax command

```
# mkdir -m 700 -p /zpool/zones/10gr2
# cd /zpool/zones/10gr2/
# ls ../..
oracle10gr2.pax  zones
# pax -r@f ../../oracle10gr2.pax
# zonecfg -z oracle10gr2
oracle10gr2: No such zone configured
Use 'create' to begin configuring a new zone.
zonecfg:oracle10gr2> create -a /zpool/zones/10gr2
zonecfg:oracle10gr2> exit
```

Attach the new zone to the new host

```
# zoneadm -z oracle10gr2 attach
These packages installed on this system were not installed on the source system:
        SUNWpostgr-82-client (11.10.0,REV=2007.04.27.13.04)
        SUNWpostgr-82-contrib (11.10.0,REV=2007.04.27.13.04)
        SUNWpostgr-82-devel (11.10.0,REV=2007.04.27.13.04)
        SUNWpostgr-82-libs (11.10.0,REV=2007.04.27.13.04)
        SUNWpostgr-82-server (11.10.0,REV=2007.04.27.13.04)
        SUNWpostgr-82-server-data-root (11.10.0,REV=2007.04.27.13.04)
        SUNWpostgr-83-server-data-root (11.10.0,REV=2008.06.05.09.31)
```

At this point, we'll have to upgrade the new zone's packages, so run with the -u option:

```
# zoneadm -z oracle10gr2 attach -u
Getting the list of files to remove
Removing 5 files
Remove 12 of 12 packages
Installing 24 files
Add 19 of 19 packages
Installation of these packages generated warnings: SUNWpostgr-82-server-data-root
Updating editable files
The file </var/sadm/system/logs/update_log> within the zone contains a log of the zone update.
# zoneadm -z oracle10gr2 boot
# zlogin -C oracle10gr2
```